# Delete records with two identical column values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
Location   E-Mail            Name          Language      Creation Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
D          max@gmx.net       Max           de            19:06:00  <-- A
D          peter@outlook.com Peter         en            19:10:00
D          lisa@google.com   Lisa          en            17:39:00
E          tom@hotmail.com   Tom           fr            05:00:00  <-- B
E          carl@gmx.net      Carl          en            09:01:00
D          max@gmx.net       Max           en            17:45:00  <-- A
D          max@gmx.net       Mike          de            17:45:00  <-- A
E          tom@hotmail.com   Tom           de            06:00:00  <-- B
```

I want to identify every record, where `Location` AND `E-Mail` are the same, delete the "duplicates" and keep only the newest record. If the creation time is the same (A), then it doesn't matter, which record is deleted.

The result-table should be:

```
Location   E-Mail            Name          Language      Creation Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
D          peter@outlook.com Peter         en            19:10:00
D          lisa@google.com   Lisa          en            17:39:00
E          tom@hotmail.com   Tom           fr            05:00:00  <-- B
E          carl@gmx.net      Carl          en            09:01:00
D          max@gmx.net       Mike          de            17:45:00  <-- A
```

Because the table is very long, the solution should be speedy. :-)

Thanks for every hint!

Cheers, Holger

Comment: Do you have a primary key for the table?

Comment: @shadowjfaith: No primary key. I'm planning to use the combination of 'Location' and 'E-Mail' as primary key in the resulting table...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `(Location, EMail)` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by the descending `CreationTime`.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH NewestData AS
(
   SELECT 
       Location, EMail, Name, Language, CreationTime,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location, EMail 
                                  ORDER BY CreationTime DESC)
   FROM 
       dbo.YourTableNameHere
)
DELETE FROM NewestData
WHERE RowNum > 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" (newest) entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `(Location, EMail)` tuple) - ordered by the `CreationTime` in a descending order.

So the newest entry for each `(Location, EMail)` tuple has a value of `1` for its `RowNum`, any "duplicates" have values larger than `1`  - so I just delete away all those "duplicates" - and you're done!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working with MS SQL-Server 2008, so should be fine! I test it and report back :-)